# Load videos and play them at the same time

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I was wondering how to load two or more video or audio files at once, and then wait for them all to be ready before playing.

The current way I've listed below seems to work for the most part, however, this can sometimes not fully wait for both to be ready to play through (since the oncanplay method is attached to different videos sources). This can of course cause issues when I want multiple file types to be completely synchronized.

```
function loadSources() {

  var videoOne = document.getElementById("first");
  videoOne.src = "first-video.mp4";

  var videoTwo = document.getElementById("second");
  videoTwo.src = "second-video.mp4";

  videoOne.oncanplay = function() {
    videoOne.play();
  };

  videoTwo.oncanplay = function() {
    videoTwo.play();
  };
}
```

How would I go about combining multiple oncanplay events into one?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by listening for a `load` event on the elements and incrementing an integer as resources are loaded. It would look something like the following code:

```
const videoOne = document.getElementById("first");
let loaded = 0;
videoOne.addEventListener("load", () => {
    if (loaded === RESOURCE_NUM - 1) {  // resources required to be loaded
        // play the video / audio files
    }
    else {
        loaded++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah okay, I think I understand. So basically in the case I posted about, I'd have RESOURCE_NUM be 2. The part I'm not understanding though is how to play both at the same time. For instance, once the load event fires, I see that the integer will increase, from the else statement, but how will it check back to to actually play the video?

It seems like it will just increase the integer then do nothing else after?

Comment: When the `if` statement is true (loaded === 2), you can execute `play` on as many resources as you'd like. At this point everything will have already been loaded. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: But won't the statement be false, default to the else, just run loaded++ first? After it executes the else, won't we need to rerun it to check again?

Comment: Okay so we should either initialize loaded to 1 or check if loaded is equal to RESOURCE_NUM - 1. I'll edit the answer.